# Disabling the # in angular ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How do I remove the '#' from the urls of the angular ui-router.

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

The above thing doesn't works. It works for when we click on the ui-sref attribute, but when I want to go to a link directly, it doesn't.

Eg.
When I'm on http://www.example.com and click on an element with ui-sref="about", it takes me to http://www.example.com/about. But if I got to http://www.example.com/about by typing the url, it gives an error.

Answer (score 1):

Angular app is a single page application.

Basically, the hash will be removed by the app, if present, when you are navigating through app's router, because you configured it so in `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`.

But if you type the url in the browser, it becomes external to the angular app. The route `/about` doesn't exist technically. Try typing `http://www.example.com/#/about` in your url. The `#` will get removed.

Comment: But then what's the point removing that #?
I want a customer to enter the URL without a #, only then it makes sense. Is that possible anyway? @vamshi-suram